# Does Hordemaster epic destiny perk trigger once per ally or once overall?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, action-economy, epic-tier, dark-sun

I want to understand exactly how Dark Sun's "Hordemaster" Level 30 feature works (*Dark Sun Campaign Setting*, page 100).

> **Horde Attack (30th level)**: Once per encounter, when you or an ally within 5 squares of you first becomes bloodied in an encounter, you and each ally within 5 squares of you can use an at-will attack power as a free action.

**Interpretation 1:** The perk is equivalent to a no-action encounter power that you can use once per encounter. It is triggered when you or an ally within 5 squares of you becomes bloodied for the first time in an encounter. This would grant one bout of free-action attacks in total.

**Interpretation 2:** When you or an ally within 5 squares of you first becomes bloodied in an encounter, you can, once per encounter for that ally, grant yourself and all nearby allies an extra attack. This would grant as many bouts of free-action at-will attacks per encounter as there are sufficiently close allies that get bloodied.

Interpretation 2 is obviously stronger, but Level 30 features are generally pretty bonkers. Interpretation 1 seemed less convincing as a Level 30 feature, compared to many others. However, this could be a misunderstanding of game balance on my part.

Part of my question is wondering whether a single round of extra at-will attacks for a team -- comparable, I suppose, to everyone getting a conditional extra (nerfed) action point -- especially strong?

Regardless, is Interpretation 1 rules-as-intended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### This works once per encounter

The feature says:

> **Once per encounter**, when you or an ally within 5 squares of you first becomes bloodied in an encounter, you and each ally within 5 squares of you can use an at-will attack power as a free action.

The way that senctence is constructed, the main clause is "Once per encounter you and each ally can use an at-will attack power as a free action.", with the ellipsis subordinate clause adding the condtion that triggers it: "when you or an ally within 5 squares of you first becomes bloodied in an encounter". If you could trigger it every time an ally was bloodied in an encounter, it would not be *once per encounter* any more.

Interpretation 1 is rules-as-intended.